# Is there a Wordpress Plugin for Google Cloud Messaging (GCM)

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-messaging

I'm looking for a plugin for the Wordpress environment for Google Cloud Messaging.  Is one available or would it be difficult to create?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is at pushappmaker.com I wrote it it can send messages to iPhone and Android devices

Comment: Can you provide a link ? pushappmaker.com not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Check out the WordPress repository.
There is a plugin called WP GCM
Its a very great one and has some great extras!

http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-gcm/